# Select column with same date in columne

Tags: sql

I could not find correct sql query for the following problem

This is the table

```
+------+----------+---------+-------+
| id   | empname  | superid | CTC   |
+------+----------+---------+-------+
|    1 | Sujatha  |       2 | 56000 |
|    2 | Rajesh   |       3 | 60000 |
|    3 | Vasanthi |       4 | 65000 |
|    4 | Murali   |       5 | 75000 |
+------+----------+---------+-------+
```

I should print `empname` and the `supervisor` name. The `supervisor` is also an employee.

I tried several queries but could not find answer. Please help.

I tried to format the table but this platform is not allowing

Comment: Do a self join!

Comment: Whats with the date in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the table name be employee
This is the query:

```
SELECT e1.empname, e2.empname 
FROM employee AS e1 INNER JOIN employee AS e2 
ON e1.superid=e2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by `SELF JOIN`

```
SELECT id AS employeeid
    ,e.empname
    ,s.empname AS supervisor
    ,e.CTC AS employeeCTC
FROM Employees AS e
INNER JOIN Employees AS s ON e.superid = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (if your table name is "mytable" for exemple) :

```
SELECT emp_table.empname, super_table.empname
FROM mytable emp_table
INNER JOIN mytable super_table ON emp_table.id = super_table.superid
```

Comment: My solution is for MySQL

Comment: This solution also works. Thanks for your answer. I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
Select empname
, supervisorName 
from employee, supervisor 
where employee.empId=supervisor.empId AND 
     employee.superId=supervisor.superId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  em.empname,
  sp.empname
FROM emp_super em
INNER JOIN emp_super sp
  ON em.id = sp.superid
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around your post, stating specifically why you believe it will solve the original problem.